# Is it possible to implement a "light" appdomain by writing a dedicated native application that would host the .NET run-time?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I have Background Job Engine that runs jobs. It could be 50 jobs at the same time. All run in a single `AppDomain`, different threads.

The problem is that it is impossible to:

- Kill a job (killing a thread is not an option)
- To get job's memory usage

Theoretically, the solution is running each job in its own `AppDomain`, but having 50 AppDomains is impractical. AppDomains are heavy and one of the reasons - they load all the assemblies, even if they are all the same.

Now I realize there is no solution from within the .NET realm, but what if my Background Job Engine was a native C++ application hosting the .NET run-time. Do I have more options there? Could I implement a sort of "light" AppDomain that would enable me to run 50 jobs each in its own "light" AppDomain?

A "light" AppDomain would use the shared set of .NET assemblies and should come up in a snap. But it still should give a fair amount of isolation, enough to allow me to bring it down along with everything running inside it. In this case, only assemblies loaded directly in this AppDomain would be unloaded. It would also be great to be able to collect the memory usage of individual "light" AppDomain.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Suppose that I could run 50 AppDomains and I am OK with whatever control that gives my over the code running in an AppDomain. Now we all understand that running 50 AppDomains is unrealistic.

But what makes it so unrealistic? I can think of one reason - the necessity to load all the assemblies, could be other reasons as well.

1. But why is it working like this?
2. Isn't it true that the assembly code is read-only?
3. Or is it because of the static variables that are mapped within the assembly code space?
4. In short, what makes the model where different AppDomains share the some assemblies so problematic?

I am not familiar with .NET runtime hosting, so I am curious whether the shared assemblies model could be implemented manually through usage of some advanced .NET runtime hosting API. In that model, the host preloads some assemblies which are shared by all the AppDomains.

Comment: You have considerably less.  Aborting code safely requires throwing away *all* the data that could have been touched by that code.  Since you no longer know how it was mutated.  The primary role of an AppDomain, unloading it also destroys all its data.  This is not possible for unmanaged code, you can't throw away its data.  You can at best only leak it.  Only running it in a separate process allows getting rid of it.  50 separate processes is *not* better than 50 appdomains :)

Comment: You can't kill an AppDomain. You can attempt to terminate it but it's equivalent to aborting threads which are currently running in this AppDomain.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least two possible .NET-only solutions, with various trade-offs for each.

1. Each job gets its own thread (or use async/await if you want to reduce threads). Each job has a Cancel() method that sets both a boolean flag and a ManualResetEvent.  Then during any async operation, you use WaitHandle.WaitAny(workEvent, cancelEvent) which gives you the option to cancel the current async work.  At various points in your code you can also check whether the cancel boolean flag is set, and terminate the job if it is.  You can optionally do cleanup after cancellation if desired.  When your jobs allocate or deallocate resources, manually keep a running counter of the subset of resources which are likely to consume the most memory, as a rough approximation of memory usage.  This won't give you exact numbers, but relative to other jobs it should help you identify the worst offenders, and could give you more detailed insight into why they're consuming memory.
2. Break this into two .NET executables: a job controller, and a worker.  The job controller can create as many worker processes as it wants using Process.Start(), and can track exact memory consumption for each Process.  It can also terminate individual processes and be guaranteed that all resources will be freed.  Downsides: additional process overhead, and potential messiness left behind if cleanup is needed.

Edit: a few more options

3. Implement your jobs as Tasks and use [CancellationTokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx).
4. Use something like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) to manage your jobs.  It [supports cancellation tokens](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html).

Comment: I am aware of all of these options. The question is not about how to implement the jobs correctly - we already have over 200 jobs and no one is going to open them up now. I may not like it, but that is how the things are. That is why I am not asking "how to implement a cancelable job". Thanks for the write-up, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Oh wow. Good luck. It seems the best option is #2 then, at least from my list of options. I've done crazy stuff with AppDomains in the past but don't recommend it. It can add significant complexity.

Comment: Please, elaborate crazy. I might be interested to learn about it.

Comment: This was over ten years ago, back in the .NET 1.1 days.  I created unit tests to test an HTTP messaging system that had shared singletons in the client and server, meaning they couldn't both run in the same AppDomain.  To remotely control the messaging system instances in other AppDomains, I had to add conditional compilation to my DEBUG builds so that the classes I wanted to control were MarshalByRefObjects.  At the time, .NET Remoting was the preferred way to communicate between AppDomains.  You can create instances of objects in other AppDomains with CreateInstanceAndUnwrap.

Comment: Child domains can get a reference to the parent from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("parent") and then call DoCallBack(someDelegate) to send updates back to the parent domain.  It ended up working well, but it just felt really awkward to do things that felt like they should be much more straight-forward.  Maybe things have improved since .NET 1.1.